# Code snippet gives "Script error." message

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

Today when I tried to answer a question with a snippet it gave me a strange "Script error." message. I can run the sample code and it works, but I still get the error. Is this a bug or am I not understanding something about Stack Snippets?

```js
$('.local-intranets').addClass('class');
```

```css
.class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="local-intranets">
 Test
</div>
```

Image:

[image: Screenshot #1 of snippet with error message]

After edit by @suraj  I can run the snippet in this question and still get the same error.  I'm using
Google Chrome,
version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image: Screenshot #2 of snippet with error message]

Comment: Its not repro in your question...

Comment: When I run this code from question i still face same problem. I am using Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I cant repro in Firefox stable or chrome stable.. both latest in WIndows. Also you meant this question right?

Comment: What you see in browser console? (F12, go to tab console)

Comment: @Grundy Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal, this error usually happens when you try output to console jQuery object, are you sure that this not output from previous version code. Also, if you disable embedded console, you can see that error away

Comment: did you try without any extensions? maybe they are interfering?

Comment: I am sure this is  not output from previous version code.

Comment: I am not  using any extensions.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal, can you try change jquery version to newer like 2.2.4 or even 3.x?

Comment: Anyway, if you uncheck _Show console_ flag in snippet error should away even if you look in native browser console

Comment: @ShreeKhanal In what file does your browser report the error?

Comment: Not reproducible for me _Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)_

Comment: It's not reproducible by most of the people and even me, try to test the same link in different browser, incognito window(in chrome), clear your cache, and confirm if it's really causing a problem.

Comment: I found why I get error. Extension `DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials 018.1.25` .When I disable this extension error disappear.

Comment: It was happening to me, too. So it's DuckDuckGo's fault. Damn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions that are known to cause this problem:

- DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials (from [Shree Khanal](/users/965146/shree-khanal)'s [comment](/questions/362438/code-snippet-gives-script-error-message#comment552705_362438))
- [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) (from [NtFreX](/users/6583901/ntfrex)'s [comment](/questions/362438/code-snippet-gives-script-error-message/365182#comment573552_365182))

Disabling the offending extension(s) should solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and do not have this extension. So it can also be because of other extensions. It works when I disable my extensions. It's the [`Custom JavaScript for websites`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) extension which breaks it in my case.